# How to enable and get Perfromance counters for Window Azure

Tags: azure, console-application, performancecounter, system.diagnostics

I have developed one web application for monitoring azure application (Webrole) by console(EXE) application attaching in startup task with azure application and that EXE will send data periodically for cpu usage, memory and asp.net total session, however i have done it using WMI Query as per below.

**CPU Usage**

```
 ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = ExecuteWMIQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
```

**Memory**

```
 queryCollection = ExecuteWMIQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
```

**asp.net Session**

```
queryCollection = ExecuteWMIQuery("Select SessionsActive from Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications");
```

But when i testing it with window Azure then i am getting error in event log like below

> Disabled performance counter data collection from the
>   "ASP.NET_64_2.0.50727" service because the performance counter library
>   for that service has generated one or more errors. The errors that
>   forced this action have been written to the application event log.
>   Correct the errors before enabling the performance counters for this
>   service

---

> Windows cannot open the 64-bit extensible counter DLL
>   ASP.NET_64_2.0.50727 in a 32-bit environment. Contact the file vendor
>   to obtain a 32-bit version. Alternatively if you are running a 64-bit
>   native environment, you can open the 64-bit extensible counter DLL by
>   using the 64-bit version of Performance Monitor. To use this tool,
>   open the Windows folder, open the System32 folder, and then start
>   Perfmon.exe.

That's why i would like to change my logic with System.Diagnostic class and want to get CPU Usage , available memory and asp.net total session using that class.

I have connect RDP of azure application and run **perfmon.exe** and see the available performance counter however i found only one counter %processor time, so i need to add another counter.

Can anyone please suggest me that how can i enable it and fetch using C# in my EXE application (will be in startup task)?

Your replays can be really helpful me to achieve my goal

Thanks in Advance!
Arun.

.

Comment: So, did you check the event log?

Comment: @Jeremy yes i have checked that

Comment: ... and? What did the log say?

Comment: @Jeremy i have mentioned it in above question

Comment: "The errors that forced this action have been written to the application event log. " Check the _application_ event log - I'd expect something to the effect of that the requested counters not being available -- Azure is a 64-bit system so the counters are different than 32-bit Windows.

Comment: @Jeremy  I have added 2nd error in my question as per you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your application has been built as a 32-bit application. Try rebuilding with the configuration manager set to "Any CPU", then redeploying.

Also, check to see if you received any warnings on deployment about 32-bit DLLs.

Comment: some time it worked and some times not. can i try as per 2nd error start Perfmon.exe in my startup task?

Answer (score 0):

Michael washam has some really good posts on using the azure powershell cmdlets for azure diagnostics and performance. IMHO powershell is the best way to go with azure.

Michael's blog.
http://michaelwasham.com/

Comment: it's very difficult to understand for me at this stage :)

Comment: Same here, I only started working with the cmdlets this week and they take some getting used to!